# how to sort book titles in order without a, an, the using oracle pl sql function

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, plsql, sql-order-by

I am trying to arrange the book title in alphabetical order through oracle pl/sql function but want to avoid 'a', 'an', 'the' in the sorting. I have tried create function using different functions such as LTRIM, TRIM, REPLACE but the the book title are not sorted when I use ORDER BY FUNCTION NAME.

Code for Create function is -

```
 create or replace function sort_string (p_title in varchar2)
 return varchar2
 as
 begin
 return replace(replace(replace(p_title,'THE',''),'a',''),'an','');
end;
/
```

and the following SQL to retrieve data

```
 select book_title
 from books
 order by sort_string(book_title);
```

Comment: Can you add some examples of book_title data.

Comment: create table books
  (Id integer,
  book_title varchar2(100));
  
  insert into books values (1, 'A reference to the Oracle analytical functions');
  insert into books values (2, 'Croaking tetra from South America');
  insert into books values (1, 'The Animals of Peru');
  insert into books values (1, 'The Grand Medieval Bestiary');
  insert into books values (1, 'The ancient Cities');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use a function at all? Also, be sure to test with titles that begin with the letter 'A' but not the *word* 'A ' and so forth. The `ltrim( string, 'A ' )` function will return 'Great Day' when passed 'A Great Day' but it will also return 'nother Great Day' when passed 'Another Great Day'. This will not work as you expect. Note the titles I've added in the <kbd>[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/932df/4/0)</kbd>

```
select *
from   books
order by case when Book_title like 'A %'
                   then LTrim( book_title, 'A ' )
              when Book_title like 'An %'
                   then LTrim( book_title, 'An ' )
              when Book_title like 'The %'
                   then LTrim( book_title, 'The ' )
              else Book_title end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sort_string(
    p_title IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN trim(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(p_title,'A ',''),'An ',''),'The ',''));
END;
/
CREATE TABLE book
  ( bookid INT, book_title VARCHAR(100)
  );
INSERT
INTO book VALUES
  (
    1,
    'A reference to the Oracle analytical functions'
  );
INSERT INTO book VALUES
  (2, 'Croaking tetra from South America'
  );
INSERT INTO book VALUES
  (3, 'The Animals of Peru'
  );
INSERT INTO book VALUES
  (4, 'The Grand Medieval Bestiary'
  );
INSERT INTO book VALUES
  (5, 'The ancient Cities'
  );
SELECT sort_string(BOOK_TITLE),book_title
FROM BOOK
ORDER BY nlssort(sort_string(BOOK_TITLE),'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI');
```

Comment: the answer is far better than I was getting earlier but it is not expected. I wanted to sort them using the PL/SQL function.

Comment: I have edited my answer please check my new code as you expected.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine on the set of values used in the code. But it still does not give the results on my datasets

Comment: insert into book values (1, 'A reference to the Oracle analytical functions');
 insert into book values (2, 'Croaking tetra from South America');
 insert into book values (3, 'The Animals of Peru');
 insert into book values (4, 'The Grand Medieval Bestiary');
 insert into book values (5, 'The ancient Cities');

Answer (score 1):

What about the following sort function which uses a regular expression:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SORT_STRING(P_TITLE IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
  RETURN UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(P_TITLE, '^([a|an|the]+) (.*)$', '\2, \1', 1, 1, 'i'));
END SORT_STRING;
```

It will put the occurencies of 'a','an' or 'the' at the end of the string and return an uppercase-string for sorting.
With modification, it can be also used for a formatted output.

The execution plan should be checked for both versions on larger datasets.